# Why is a 1 being printed at the end of BFS?

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

Here's a simple Breadth First Search on an undirected graph.
The question is to find whether or not a path exists between a source and a destination node. The code works, but I don't understand why a `1` is being printed at the very end.

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool BFS(unordered_map<int, vector<int>> &umap, int source, int dest) {
    
    queue<int> q;
    vector<int> v;
    q.push(source);
    
    while (!q.empty()) {
        int front = q.front();

        if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), front) == v.end()) {//element is not visited yet
            cout << static_cast<char>(front) << " -> ";
            if (front == dest)
                return true;
            v.push_back(front);

            for (auto &i: umap[front])
                q.push(i);
        }
        q.pop();
    }
    return false;
}
int main() {
    unordered_map<int, vector<int>> umap;
    umap['i'] = {'j', 'k'}; 
    umap['j'] = {'i'};
    umap['k'] = {'i', 'm', 'p'};
    umap['m'] = {'k'};
    umap['p'] = {'k'};
    umap['o'] = {'n'};
    umap['n'] = {'o'};
    
    cout << endl
         << "------------BFS------------"
         << endl;
    cout << BFS(umap, 'j', 'm');
    
}
```

Output:

```
------------BFS------------
j -> i -> k -> m -> 1
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `cout << BFS(umap, 'j', 'm');` says, "Print the value returned by `BFS`", which happens to be a `bool`. Unless you tell `<<` to render a `bool` with `true` or `false`, with [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha), `<<` will print a 1 or a 0, so it looks like `BFS` is returning `true`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but it looks like the code expects nodes to be identified by a single character: `umap['i'] = ...` and `std::cout << static_cast<char>(front)`, but everything in fact traffics in `int` values. Seems like things would be clearer if all the data structures that dealt with identifiers treated them as `char` rather than `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first comment on this question sums it up - I overlooked the fact that I am printing a `bool` (`cout << BFS(umap, 'j', 'm');`), so a `1` is expected in this case where a path is found (the value is `true`).